# How to get file path after download using File Pipeline in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I download file using FilePipeline in Scrapy. It downloaded successfully which has a message below.

```
{'file_urls': [u'https://avt.mkklcdnv3.com/avatar_225/3635-a_world_that_i_rule.jpg'], 
'files': 
   [{
            'checksum': '6eae71709357f85fba123165c6e64256',
             'path': 'full/7d821d27c3b718d9a24b36e8ab1ae0c0c2607eb8.jpg',
             'url': 'https://avt.mkklcdnv3.com/avatar_225/3635-a_world_that_i_rule.jpg'
   }]

}
```

I want to get the 'path' in the 'files' to save into my database. 
Thank you

Comment: The question is too vague to understand. Would you please provide some more details?

Answer (score 1):

The saved file is in the `path` value, in your example `'full/7d821d27c3b718d9a24b36e8ab1ae0c0c2607eb8.jpg'`

If you want to get the full (absolute) path, you need to use either the `os` module or `pathlib`:

```
saved_file_path = files[0]['path']  # 'full/7d821d27c3b718d9a24b36e8ab1ae0c0c2607eb8.jpg'

import os
full_path = os.path.abspath(saved_file_path)

from pathlib import Path
full_path = Path(saved_file_path).absolute()
```

Comment: I don't know which the variable contains this information(message). Because it only appears in the command line when I run "scrapy crawl spider"

Answer (score 0):

The output path is whatever you define in the [FILES_STORE](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#std:setting-FILES_STORE) setting.

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody will need it.
You can extend from [Media Pipelines](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#module-scrapy.pipelines.files) and access [results](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline.item_completed) in `item_completed`

```
from scrapy.pipelines.files import FilesPipeline

class DownloadPipeline(FilesPipeline):

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        print(results)

        return item
```

The results will be something like

```
[
    (
        True,
        {
            "checksum": "2b00042f7481c7b056c4b410d28f33cf",
            "path": "full/0a79c461a4062ac383dc4fade7bc09f1384a3910.jpg",
            "url": "http://www.example.com/files/product1.pdf",
            "status": "downloaded",
        },
    ),
    (False, Failure(...)),
]
```